# What could be the best approach to create a query to select "from date ", "to date" from a list of single column dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I need to find the start date and end date of each leased car, but only have one single column of when lease started. The logic to follow is that the start date of a lease marks the end date of the previous one. Last entry will have as end date the current system date (getdate)

-thanks,

```html
plate  leaseNumber leaseStartDate
abc01  1           1/1/2000
abc01  2           1/20/2010
abc01  3           3/15/2010
xyz02  4           1/1/2000
xyz02  5           2/20/2000


**expected result:**

plate lease fromDate  toDate
abc01 1     1/1/2000  1/19/2010
abc01 2     1/20/2010 3/14/2010 
abc01 3     3/15/2010  getdate()
xyz02 4     1/1/2000  2/19/2000
xyz02 5     2/20/2000 getdate()
```

I've already tried getting the min date and subtracting a day from the next date available and updating in batches to no avail .

Comment: you are assuming that the `lease` will immediately starts a new one when one ended ?

Comment: Correct. If it's the last one: max(start date)... it means it's still going (current), hence the "getdate()" part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lead()`, but you don't need `coalesce()`.  `lead()` takes three arguments.  The third is the default if there is no following row.  So:

```
    lead(dateadd(day, -1, leaseStartDate), 1,
         getdate()
        ) over (partition by plate
                order by leaseStartDate
               ) as toDate
```

Comment: Nice ... 10 out of 8K misfired. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can use `LEAD()` window function to get the "next" row's date. Subtract one day and that is the toDate

```
; 
with 
your_data as
(
    select plate = 'abc01', leaseNumber = 1, leaseStartDate = convert(date, '2000-01-01') union all
    select plate = 'abc01', leaseNumber = 2, leaseStartDate = '2010-01-20' union all
    select plate = 'abc01', leaseNumber = 3, leaseStartDate = '2010-03-15' union all
    select plate = 'xyz02', leaseNumber = 4, leaseStartDate = '2000-01-01' union all
    select plate = 'xyz02', leaseNumber = 5, leaseStartDate = '2000-02-20'
) 
select  plate, 
        lease    = leaseNumber, 
        fromDate = leaseStartDate,
        toDate   = coalesce(dateadd(day, -1, lead(leaseStartDate) over (partition by plate 
                                                               order by leaseStartDate)), 
                            getdate())
from    your_data
order by lease
```

Answer (score 1):

I create a table with name Q1 for your problem with this structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Q1](
    [plate] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [leaseNumber] [int] NULL,
    [leaseStartDate] [date] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

and inserted your data and wrote below query i think this is correct

```
SELECT  plate = plate,
        lease = leaseNumber,
        fromDate  = leaseStartDate,
        toDate  = ISNULL(LEAD(DATEADD(DAY , -1, leaseStartDate)) OVER (PARTITION BY plate ORDER BY leaseNumber),GETDATE())
FROM    Q1
ORDER BY leaseNumber
```

this query generate your output exactly